# How to Find best match using hashset(Of String) ignore case

Tags: vb.net, function, hashset

I found the following function to compare text to a list(Of String). Now I want to know if it's possible to make it ignore case in the comparison & if so how would I change this code?

```
    Public Shared Function FindBestMatch(ByVal stringToCompare As String, ByVal strs As IEnumerable(Of String)) As String
        Dim strCompareHash As HashSet(Of String) = stringToCompare.Split(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(32)).ToHashSet
        Dim maxIntersectCount As Integer = 0
        Dim bestMatch As String = String.Empty
        For Each str As String In strs
            Dim strHash As HashSet(Of String) = str.Split(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(32)).ToHashSet
            Dim intersectCount As Integer = strCompareHash.Intersect(strHash).Count
            If (intersectCount > maxIntersectCount) Then
                maxIntersectCount = intersectCount
                bestMatch = str
            End If

        Next
        Return bestMatch
    End Function
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated

All the suggestions I've seen I haven't been able to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HashSet(Of T)` class has a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-hashset-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))) that let you specify the comparer. The same applies to the LINQ method [`ToHashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-tohashset-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))).

```
Dim comparer As IEqualityComparer(Of String) = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
Dim strCompareHash As HashSet(Of String) = stringToCompare.
    Split(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(32)).
    ToHashSet(comparer)
```

The whole method could be rewritten with LINQ to be more compact:

```
Public Shared Function FindBestMatch(ByVal stringToCompare As String, ByVal strs As IEnumerable(Of String)) As String
    Dim comparer As IEqualityComparer(Of String) = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
    Dim strCompareHash As HashSet(Of String) = stringToCompare.Split(ChrW(32)).ToHashSet(comparer)
    return strs.
        Select(Function(s) (Str:=s, Tokens:=s.Split(ChrW(32)))).
        OrderByDescending(Function(x) strCompareHash.Intersect(x.Tokens, comparer).Count()). 
        First().Str
End Function
```

This assumes that `strs` is never null or empty, you might want to ensure that and return `Nothing` early. It would also be good to add an (optional) parameter to be able to pass the `IEqualityComparer(Of String)`.

Comment: Hi @Tim, Many thanks. I'll play around with this tonight when at my desktop machine. strs gets checked for list count > 0 before calling the function so no danger there

Comment: `Intersect` is an extension method to `IEnumerable` so it does not benefit from the source being a HashSet nor will it use the hashset's comparer.

Comment: @Magnus: good catch, i have added the comparer to `Intersect`